# How to recover from master failure in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, etcd

I have three nodes multi-master kubernetes(1.17.3) cluster(Stacked control plane and etcd nodes),

```
11.11.11.1 - master1
11.11.11.2 - master2
11.11.11.3 - master3
```

So before going to productions, I am trying possible failures and did below steps

**Graceful Removal of Master Nodes**

- `Run kubectl drain 11.11.11.3` on master3
- `kubeadm reset` on master 3
- `kubectl delete node 11.11.11.3` on master3

So by applying above steps all pods are running on master 1 and 2, it removes entries from `kubeadm-conf` configmap and also from `etcd`, infact i run above steps on master2 and still one master is up and running and i can run `kubectl`.

**Non-Graceful Removal of Master Nodes**

- I shutdown master3 but dont face any issue still two master accessible and i can run `kubectl` and do administrations.
- As soon as i shut master2 i have no access to `kubectl` and its saying apiserver is not accessible. ***How i can recover master1 in this situation?***

This can happen that two nodes may have hardware issue in production, from my search it look like etcd issue but how i can access etcd and remove master2 and master3, i thought to do `docker ps` and `docker exec <etcd container>` but docker ps is not showing etcd container.

Comment: If your etcd cluster is on you masters and you shut down master2 and master3 at the same time etcd will not be able to form a quorum so nothing will work. Best to have a 5+ etcd cluster.

Answer (score 2):

A topic **near and dear** to my heart.

The short version is:

1. create an etcd snapshot from the surviving etcd node
2. create a new, 3-node "disposable" etcd cluster, restoring from that snapshot
3. stop `master1`'s etcd member
4. reset its state (`rm -rf /var/lib/etcd`, and delete the server and peer certs unless you have used the same CA for the disposable cluster -- something I highly recommend but may not be possible for a variety of reasons)
5. join it to the new, now healthy disposable etcd cluster
6. now you can either bring the other masters back online, joining them to that new cluster until you have a new quorum, and tear down the disposable cluster, or you can walk over the disposable etcd members, removing them from the cluster one at a time until only `master1` remains in your "cluster of one"

I have had **great** success using [etcdadm](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/etcdadm/releases) to automate all of those steps I just described, with the bad news being that you have to build the `etcdadm` binary yourself, because they don't -- as of this message -- attach built artifacts to their releases

In the future, you'll want to include `etcdctl member remove $my_own_member_id` from any orderly master teardown process, since if a member just disappears from an etcd cluster, that's damn near fatal to the cluster. There is [an etcd issue](https://github.com/etcd-io/etcd/issues/3329#issuecomment-133771609) speaking to the fact that etcd really is fragile, and you need a bigger team running it than you do kubernetes itself :-(

Comment: How i can create snapshot from surviving node? as i mentioned its "Stacked control plane and etcd nodes" and i am not able to access etcd container on surviving node.

Comment: Was the etcd container running _in cluster_ style "stacked," or merely running on the master nodes style stacked? Also, did you run `docker ps -a`, to show stopped containers, or just literally `docker ps`? It has been my experience that kubelet continues to run Pods even with the loss of the control plane

Comment: Please also [edit your question](https://serverfault.com/posts/1020224/edit) to include more details of what you have already tried and the results of those experiments. SF is not "ssh commands over email," so you'll need to write down what you've done rather than go back-and-forth forcing us to ask clarifying questions

Comment: I have updated answer, hope it might clarify my intention in question.

Answer (score 1):

Keeping in view my findings and testing, To restore the full functionality of your k8s cluster, make a remaining etcd node a standalone etcd cluster. Follow below steps

As we lost two master nodes out of three and now etcd pod on remaining node is not able to complete quorum so this static pod is continuously failing and exiting and you cant do `etcdctl member remove <node>`

**Stop the etcd pod:**

- `mv /etc/kubernetes/manifest/etcd.yaml /backup`
- `mv /var/lib/etcd/member /backup/`

**Temporarily force a new cluster on the etcd host:**

- `cp /backup/etcd.yaml etcd.yaml.bak`
- edit `/backup/etcd.yaml` and change following values

> etcd.yaml

```
Remove lost nodes(master2 and master3) from initial cluster
- --initial-cluster=master1=https://10.11.158.114:2380

Remove following line
- --initial-cluster-state=existing

Add Following line
- --force-new-cluster
```

**Restart the etcd pod:**

```
 cp /backup/etcd.yaml /etc/kubernetes/manifest/
```

Remove the `--force-new-cluster` command from `/etc/kubernetes/manifest/etcd.yaml` as it will force every time.

**Restore to original state** (if possible)

if master2 and master3 were not crash and lost due to other reason(mean disk and data is available) then as soon as these masters are available you can do following steps to go to original state

```
cd /etc/kubernetes/manifest
rm -rf etcd.yaml
cd /var/lib/etcd
rm -rf member
cp -R /backup/member /var/lib/etcd/
cp /backup/etcd.yaml /etc/kubernetes/manifest/
```

This is how things works for me, Please suggest if i can optimize these steps.

Comment: I also have the same issues about restore etcd. 
I follow your steps when restore first master is good. 

but master2  and master3  don't work. 
its log as the below

"caller":"embed/config_logging.go:169","msg":"rejected connection","remote-addr":"192.168.50.41:55540","server-name":"","error":"tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake"

do you know how to fix it ?